# Get value of a specific input using ".find()"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the value of an input. In my application, I want to update an entry in my database for each row. So, when I click on the button, I want the values of the corresponding row.

```
$('.ajouter_un_sol').click(function(){
       var id_sol = $(this).find('.nom_sol').value;
        alert(id_sol);
    });
```

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gabhan7/) for you to see what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to get the value of a row.

Can someone tell me how I should do please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$('.button').click(function(){
        var age = $(this).parent().parent().children('td').find('.age').val();
    alert(age);
})
```

Comment: I updated some things and it works with your method, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var id_sol = $(this).closest("tr").find('.nom_sol').val()
```

`.value` is a javscript property so you need to use `.val()`.

You are trying to `find` the `input` inside `button` but actually it is within `td` so you need to find it in `td` within the parent `tr`

Answer (score 0):

use `.val()` in jquery.

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea.

```
var id_sol = $(this).find('.nom_sol').val();
```

for your scenario use

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('td .age').val();
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0gabhan7/4/)

Comment: I've already tried but it doesn't work. It says "undefined" :/

Comment: You can have it on my link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, instead of

```
var age = $(this).find('.age').value;
```

try

```
var age = $(this).closest('tr').find('.age').val();
```

closest('tr') finds the nearest ancestor of type 'tr', and then you search down for the age field from there.